# How can I see someone's deleted questions or answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, privileges, deleted-questions

I know some users can see the deleted content from other users. How are they able to do that?

Comment: You can´t. As soon as you got 10K reputation, you can do it with some limitations. As soon as you become a moderator, you can do even more (i think)...

Comment: @deviantfan There are no posts that a moderator can see that a 10 user can't.  The only relevant difference for moderators is that they can see deleted questions on a user's profile, whereas 10k users don't.

Comment: It's explained [in the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).  There's even some advice on what you are supposed to use that privilege for (under the heading `Use this privilege wisely`).  For me a key point is `Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post`

Comment: @fvu that english standard than mine I really didn't get much of a thing in that highlighted line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Users can see deleted posts (that are not their own) once they reach 10K Reputation points if they have a link to that post.

These users can also see a list of their own deleted content by searching with the term `deleted:1` at the top bar. A direct link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1

Only moderators can see/search for a list of deleted posts another user has.

Comment: ...or are Community Moderators.