# What is the policy concerning interview questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554292/is-it-correct-approach) concerns an interview question. What is the policy answering such on Stack Overflow? Is it OK to just for fun give an answer that would

- solve the problem using code?
- give the reasoning for the solution or the correctness of one's solution?
- provide hints in the right direction?

---

Here's a snapshot of the original question, which has since been deleted:

[image]

Comment: What is your concern?  That someone will use SO to get the answer during an interview?

Comment: @dan1111 You mean you _haven't_ sprinted out of the interview room to ask a technical question on StackOverflow only to return triumphantly with your answer before?

Comment: Meh.. 'Interview question' is often a blatant lie to cover up homework dumps anyway.  Luckily, in either case, they are usually no-inputs/no-outputs/no-effort/no-error-messages/no-debugging trash questions that can be readily dumped.

Comment: This is a copy/paste from Careercup.com, a site owned by Gayle McDowell.  Formerly at Google.com where she was a member of the Hiring Committee.  Copy/pasting copyrighted material without any attribution or clearance whatsoever is, well, you know.  The site moderators refuse to enforce it so there isn't much that can be done about it.  But feel free to not like it.

Comment: @HansPassant right.  it can have a nice, non-copyrighted, non-patented DCV.

Comment: Looks like I just about got away with [my interview question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35507190/560648), though even that managed to attract downvotes and closevotes from the sillies.

Comment: I also asked [an interview question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209524/finding-two-non-subsequent-elements-in-array-which-sum-is-minimal) a while back and it was well-received with many answers. I guess it's just a matter of how you phrase it, and if you really show that you've tried to solve it prior to posting on SO. (Ofcourse it has to be well-defined and applicable to a large-enough audience)

Comment: Is it a good question in it's own right? If so, we don't care. If not, downvote/close etc.

Comment: related at Progs meta: [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Comment: My god. I don't think I'd know where to start with that question in an interview.  If I get fired or quit, I may have to go back to being a cashier; I'm pretty sure my high school experience at that job would still hold up.

Comment: It's actually quite a good way for interviewers to find interesting questions and good answers.  If someone has studied up all the interview questions on SO, they probably know what they're doing anyway, and are worth hiring.

Comment: @ralph-m-rickenbach : Just out of curiosity, what's an "interview question"?

Comment: @ralph-m-rickenbach I'll add that this question (in subject) doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @konrad_firm Thank you. in the question, there was a link to a page that had a list of programming problems that where labeled 'interview questions', that is, that could be asked during job interviews to test somebody's skills.

Comment: @ralph-m-rickenbach wow, I didn't expect that:) I thought "interview" was used in the meaning of  interviewing i.e. a politician by a journalist. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @konrad_firm We tend to get a lot of question about interviews for programming jobs on stackoverflow; not so many about politicians or journalists for some reason, though.

Comment: @Alex got it :) It's because my English is far from being perfect, I didn't even know that "interview" is also an examination during recruitment. I hope that, at least, this  sentence is correct in English :)

Comment: @konrad_firm Your English is already far better than many native English speakers and writers!

Comment: @Alex thanks :) Would be cool if true :) BTW apropos deleted pages, it also would be cool if we could access those deleted questions somehow (not to answer or vote, but to understand why the question was deleted, I'm sometimes interested in this, when I'd like see what kind of questions cannot be asked on SO). This could be a link like "open it anyway (readonly)". I just wanted to live this suggestion somewhere on this page.

Comment: @konrad_firm I think if you have enough reputation on this site you can see deleted questions.   http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254056/how-can-i-see-someones-deleted-questions-or-answers

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should act according to the question's quality, regardless of where it was asked. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554292/find-lexicographic-ally-smallest-string-by-reversing-some-substring) you came across should be closed, not because it's about algorithms, but because OP is not specific, his last line was "*..then don't know what to do*".

I really don't care if the question was asked during an interview or a class, or maybe by a random in the street, what I care about is the quality of the question.
I don't like encouraging unclear questions that don't demonstrate understanding, this won't be really helping OP and future users.

Comment: Interview questions, homework questions, whatever. It doesn't really matter - either they're a _good_ question, and we treat it as we do good questions... or it isn't, and it should be downvoted or close voted accordingly.

Comment: +1 for `maybe by a random in the street`

Comment: ...random in the street... are you black hat? https://xkcd.com/356/